# Specifying the number of points per class (not per feature) when doing stratified sampling

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, feature-class, random

I am quite new to QGIS (3.16 / Win 10) and have a raster of one band with integer values from 1 to 14. I polygonized this raster in order to generate random points afterwards. The derived polgonized vector file now contains about 30,000 features, each of them assigned to one of my 14 classes.

Now, I'd like to create 30 random points per class (for accuracy assessment reasons). In the end, this should result in 14 x 30 = 420 points in total. So, only a pretty small fraction of all my features should be provided by points, the others remain without.

I tried the `Random points in polygons` and the `Random points inside polygons` tool. But obviously I can only choose the number of points per feature **BUT NOT per class**. So in the end I would have about one million (30 x 30,000) sample points, - too much for me :-).

Did I do or understand anything wrong?
If no: Is there any other tool, option or plugin to choose the number of points per class?
Or, in case there isn't, any alternative approach to reach my aim?

Comment: So for class 1, there can be 1 point in 30 different polygons, or do you want 30 points in one random polygon?

Comment: In the end, the algorithm should consider all polygones of the same class as one single 'mega'-feature or -area and distribute the 30 points randomly on it. No matter whether 0, 1, 2, 3 or more points were placed (by random) at the single polygones.

Comment: So the answer below fulfills this condition? If something is missing, it would be interesting to know what...

Answer (score 1):

1. Merge all polygons of the same class to one single multipart feature using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` (see [documentation on Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#aggregate)).
2. Run `Random points inside polygons` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?#random-points-in-polygons)) with 30 random points per feature for this new, aggregated layer.

When done, you have your points allocated correctly. You can now delete the aggregated layer.

*Screenshot, showing initial + aggregated polygons for a layer with 4 feature classes (1 to 4). Highlighted in yellow is **one multipart feature** on the aggregated layer, merging all polygons with `class=3` in a single feature. Random points are created with 10 points per feature on the aggregated layer: as you can see, the polygons contain together a total of 10 points per feature class:*

[image]